# there is no entire function f(z) which verifies that |f(z)| > |z| for every z ∈ C.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hi I came across this question, prove there is no entire function f(z) which verifies that |f(z)| > |z| for every z ∈ C.

I was gonna try use the fact that $g∈C$ such that $f(g)=0$ and maybe that function $1/|f(z)|$ is bounded. Thank you

Comment: I think it's more to do with $\frac{z}{f(z)}$ being entire and bounded.

Comment: Not $1/f(z)$. Rewrite the inequality $\lvert f(z) \rvert > \lvert z \rvert$ such that you can deduce a bounded function.

Comment: Decomposing your homework into small bits that you post as separate questions here is not optimal, to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f$ is non-zero. Let $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}, z\in\mathbb C.$

Then $|g(z)|<\frac{1}{|z|}$ for all $z.$ Thus for $|z|\geq 1$ we have
$$|g(z)|\leq \frac{1}{|z|}\leq 1 .$$
Also since $g$ is continuous on $|z|\leq 1,$ it is bounded there.

Thus $g$ is bounded on $\mathbb C.$ Thus, by Liouville's theorem, $g$ is constant. Hence $f$ is constant.

One can directly verify that a constant function does not satisfy the given hypothesis. This completes the proof.

Comment: hey thanks, would I use say f=a as the constant function then sub that into somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying?@RodgerS

Comment: for the last bit how would I show "One can directly verify that a constant function does not satisfy the given hypothesis"

Comment: Assume that $ f(z)=\alpha $ for some $ \alpha \in \mathbb C.$ Then we must have $|\alpha| > |z|$ for all $z.$ Do you see the contradiction?